# delete rdf graph data

Tags: sparql

I'm new to sparql. Can anyone tell me how I can delete an rdf graph data (eg: http://mylocalhost.com/owl/file.owl) in virtuoso. Following is how I created it:

```
db.dba.rdf_load_rdfxml_mt(file_to_string_output('/data/file.owl'), '', 'http://example.com/file.owl');
```

I did the `sparql clear graph <uri>` and `sparql drop graph <uri>`, but didn't work.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please see the following tip on differences between create, drop, clear & delete graph methods in Virtuoso:

http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtTipsAndTricksGuideCreateGraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that CLEAR GRAPH, and DROP GRAPH are SPARQL Update operations, so you might need to use a different method, or endpoint, I'm not familiar with how Virtuoso works.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I ended up clearing and reloading all the rdf triples.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that clearing the graphs does not necessarily free up space. You will notice that the main `virtuoso.db` file size may remain the same after the deletion.

If you need to delete all the RDF triples (start a clear database), you can delete (or rename) the `db` folder that virtuoso operates on.

Restart virtuoso, and you will notice that it will create a clean database.

It is a hacky way, but works well!