# Apache Marmotta Delete All Graphs using SPARQL Update

Tags: sparql, apache-marmotta

I am trying to clear all loaded graphs into my Apache Marmotta instance. I have tried several SPARQL queries to do so, but I am not able to remove the RDF/XML graph that I imported. What is the appropriate syntax to do so?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
DELETE WHERE { ?x ?y ?z }
```

Be careful, as **it deletes every triple in the database**, including the built-in ones of Marmotta.

A couple of things I did for experimenting:

1. I downloaded the [source code](http://marmotta.apache.org/download.html) of Marmotta and used the [Silver Searcher](http://geoff.greer.fm/ag/) tool for searching for `DELETE` queries with the following command:

   ```
   ag '"DELETE '
   ```

   This did not help much.
2. I navigated to the Marmotta installation directory and watched the debug log:

   ```
   tail -f marmotta-home/log/marmotta-main.log
   ```

   This showed that the parser is not able to process the query `DELETE DATA { ?s ?p ?o }`. The exception behind the "error while executing update" was:

   ```
   org.openrdf.sail.SailException: org.openrdf.rio.RDFParseException: Expected an RDF value here, found '?' [line 8]
   [followed by a long stacktrace]
   ```

   This shows that the parser does not allow variables in the query after `DELETE DATA`.
3. Based on a [related StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736107/delete-rdf-graph-data), I tried `CLEAR` / `CLEAR GRAPH` / `DROP` / `DROP GRAPH`, but they did not work.
4. I tried many combinations of `DELETE`, `*`, `?s ?p ?p` and accidentally managed to get it working with the [DELETE WHERE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteWhere) construct. According to the W3C documentation:

   > The DELETE WHERE operation is a shortcut form for the DELETE/INSERT operation where bindings matched by the WHERE clause are used to define the triples in a graph that will be deleted.

Comment: This didn't work and returned "malformed query, update failed"

Comment: @SaraLafia I think I found the solution - I updated the answer and will add some details shortly.